# How to get env from docker container in nuxtjs

Tags: docker, docker-compose, nuxt.js

How to get env in nuxt.config.js, what should i write here?

Variables from the .env file come to the container, but nuxjs does not see them, I tried to get them like this instruction https://nuxtjs.org/tutorials/moving-from-nuxtjs-dotenv-to-runtime-config/

```
export default {
    server: {
        port: 3000, // default: 3000
    },

    ...

    publicRuntimeConfig: {
        apiUrl: process.env.API_URL || 'localhost',
    },

    apollo: {
        clientConfigs: {
            default: {
            httpEndpoint: apiUrl, <<-- how to get the value????????
                 prefetch: false,
            },
        },
    },
}
```

process.env.API_URL is a dynamic value that is substituted when starting a container via docker-compose

Answer (score 0):

1. I think You can't access `this` & `this.$config` within nuxt.config as it's usable in *.vue files.

    It's for use within your app itself.  In the case you have, @nuxtjs/apollo would also have to have support for publicRuntimeConfig (I'm not sure if it does), and you would need
   unlucky to use process.env like so:

```js
apollo: {
  clientConfigs: {
    default: {
      httpEndpoint: process.env.API_URL
    }
  }
}
```

2. But there's an option!
   You can provide additional plugin to extend Apollo config which will have access to `$config` and then You can use it inside nuxt.config.js.

- Look here into GH issue > [use publicRuntimeConfig as $config in nuxt.config.js](https://github.com/nuxt-community/apollo-module/issues/258#issuecomment-652261135) maybe it'll fulfil Your needs

There is also closed FR [Using runtime config in the nuxt.config.js #8635](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/8635) on GH